# Relay parallel to wall switch: Is it safe?

Tags: power-supply, home-automation

I am currently working on a home automation project and I have the low power electronics sorted out. My setup requires me to connect a relay to the light which is simple but my design requires me to keep the original switch on the switchboard and importantly it must work alongside the relay. To clear things out, the relay must be able to turn the light on and off but at the same time, if the light is off let's say, turning the switch on must also turn the light on but if lights are on by either relay or switch, the other's state should not affect the light's state. The same logic of an OR gate basically. I don't care about the switch position or anything since the switch is like a failsafe in case the system fails. So if I connect them in parallel, should that do the trick or do I need to do something else?. If yes, is it safe? (Can't stress on this enough)

I am switching lamps on and off and would like to clarify that the wall switches are 2 position switches, the relay is a generic 2 ch relay board and I am not using any components beyond their specified range.

Comment: Look up how 3 way switches work, putting it in parallel won't get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Why not utilize one of the zillions of recently popular "smart" switches? Your solution will become software-only.

Comment: Relay contacts CAN weld shut, i.e.  permanently ON. (Ron's 3-way switch idea (more of an XOR) will let you switch the light off if that happens)

Comment: It is a design restriction that is been given and i cant modify the wall switch to not work. Also 3 way switches end up losing the state that the light was left in, in a way it does not work like the OR gate functionality that I expect. The microcontroller is dumb and cannot identify the light's state and it is not supposed to either. All it needs to know is what it has been doing to the light.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly OK to wire a relay in parallel with a switch.  If either the switch or the relay is on, the light will come on.  That sounds like the OR function you are looking for.

Whether or not it is actually safe depends on how good your wiring is.  It needs to meet the standards of the country you're in.

Comment: By safe i mean, would it draw too much current and something like that. But since I am using it on lights only, I don't think that should be much of an issue.

Comment: Essentially run the relay contacts out to the switch, so that if either is closed, the lamp is on. Depending on country, it may be unsafe to run just a "relay hot" to the lamp.

Comment: @rdtsc why is it unsafe in some countries? What is the risk? (I'm doing a similar project)

Comment: @rdtsc The safety, or otherwise, is down to the quality of your work.  For example, using the wrong colour wires could make it fail a safety inspection.

Comment: @Carlos running a "hot only" in many countries is illegal because electricity doesn't flow down only one wire; the return current must go somewhere.  Since that return current is flowing down some *other* neutral wire, this could overload that wire and start a fire and/or nuisance-trip a breaker.  So *both* wires are always ran - it is the right thing to do.  The details of these laws vary from country to country (types of valid conduit, whether it can be ran in insulated walls, etc.); really the only solution is to call an electrician for an estimate and see what they would do.

Comment: @rdtsc what you say makes sense. I live in Switzerland, and I have never seen a two-wires wall switches. I am building a similar project, and now I am not sure what would the right way be: https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same way as good old days alternating switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRYzoK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could use a dual coil latching relay. You send a short pulse to a coil to change the position. Probably you need also a measuring circuit the can determine whether the light is turned on or off. If the smart electronics fail, you still have the wall switch.

This is how similar device looks like, you install it directly into a electric wall box.

[image]